# How to efficiently print strings with time span in a stream conditions?

Tags: algorithm, stream

Suppose we get a stream string input with clear data structure:
`content:arrive time`

Below are samples:

```
AAA : 12:00:00   
ABC : 12:00:01   
ABB : 12:00:02   
ABM : 12:00:11
```

And we have a program to check this stream input and if
1) this content does not exist before, print this content;
2) if this content arrive before and the time span is less than 10 seconds, print empty;
3) if this content arrive before and the time span is more than 10 seconds, print content;

Hashtable(String, Date) is OK, and we can update the date when a new one come in.

And my question is:
What if is the string numbers are quite large and can't be stored in hashtable? Considering we are design a program that run 24*7 and hashtable becomes bigger and bigger.
Any other way we can do to solve this issue? And can we solve this with several servers?

Comment: do you mean if the input string is so large and cant be stored in a string variable ? ie more than 2^31 ?

Comment: No, i mean the string is too large can not be stroed in hashtable. Sorry for confusion, and i will update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Hashtable(String -> Date)` and a simple `Queue([Date, String])`, every time you add a new item to the hashtable add it to the queue as well.

Every few minutes pop items from the queue and remove them from the hashtable until the date isn't old enough (<10 seconds).

This way you only hold data from the last few minutes and both the hashtable and the queue won't grow too much.